# compare each 5 numbers of two array

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var count = 0;
arrA = ["6", "2", "21", "8", "4", "12"];
arrB = ["8", "2", "12", "2", "5", "11"];
```

I want to compare each element
only if if `arrA[i] > arrB[i]`, then count add 1

How to implement this in javascript?

Comment: You want to do what?  Question is very unclear.

Comment: I'm lost! for real.. `:(`

Comment: @Ele I have deployed search and rescue kittens.

Comment: @Amy what? what happens people?? Que sucede con las personas aquí!!! jejeje

Comment: I've rewrite the question, maybe I describe too simple at first time

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce the array by adding the result of compairing the numerical values.

```js
var arrA = ["6", "2", "21", "8", "4", "12"],
    arrB = ["8", "2", "12", "2", "5", "11"],
    count = arrA.reduce((c, v, i) => c + (+v > +arrB[i]), 0);
    
console.log(count);
```

Comment: How did you get this answer with this title: *compare each 5 numbers of two array*?

Comment: @Ele, the text questioned to compare items at the same index.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  However, the question as a whole it's quite unclear.  Anyway, someone thinks this is right one! hehe `:)`

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple for loop:

```
for(let i = 0; i < arrA.length; i++) {
    if (arrA[i] > arrB[i]) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

[Alternatively, `Array.forEach` would also work:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

```
arrA.forEach((value, index) => {
  if (value > arrB[index]) {
    count++;
  }
})
```

Comment: Maybe when he says count 1, he only means to advance in the loop. I mean, to do the next iteration

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) :

```js
let count = 0;
let arrA = ["6", "2", "21", "8", "4", "12"];
let arrB = ["8", "2", "12", "2", "5", "11"];  // !< A
let arrC = ["5", "1", "20", "7", "3", "11"];  // < A

let res = arrA.every((e,i) => e > arrB[i]);  //False
let res2 = arrA.every((e,i) => e > arrC[i]); //True

if(res) count++; //Doesn't trigger
if(res2) count++; //Triggers
console.log(count);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It checks if the first array wins EVERY comparison. The question asks to check how many wins the first array has. You are also not in a loop, so your output will always be 0 or 1 (count++ runs once).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array.prototype.reduce`:

```js
var arrA = ["6", "2", "21", "8", "4", "12"];
var arrB = ["8", "2", "12", "2", "5", "11"];

var count = arrA.reduce((m, o, i) => m + (o > arrB[i] ? 1 : 0), 0);
console.log(count);
```

Or, with `array.prototype.filter`:

```js
var arrA = ["6", "2", "21", "8", "4", "12"];
var arrB = ["8", "2", "12", "2", "5", "11"];

var count = arrA.filter((e, i) => e > arrB[i]).length;
console.log(count);
```